# php error my css stop working suddenly and the code had not change

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code was working fine even when was showing this error

> Error: End of file reached when inside an attribute value. Ignoring
> tag.  At line 9, column 72 r.php on line 5

But when I went to submit yesterday everything was working except the CSS. I don't see where is the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head> //show on validation I have error line 9 in this line but I am not able to see

    <title>Fma</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php 
   echo site_url();?>includes/css/style.css">
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" 
  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  </head>
   

    <body>
 

        <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>


            

        <?php include 'nav.php';?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <?php echo notification();?>
    
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
    
         <p> Hi <?php echo getter('user'); ?></p>
         <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>includes/logout.php">Logout</a>
         
    
    <?php
    }else{
        ?>
        

    <form action="includes/login.php" method="post">


            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="user name">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
    <?php } ?>

        </header>
```

Comment: please can anyone help me I have this code was working fine even when was showing this error Error: End of file reached when inside an attribute value. Ignoring tag.

At line 9, column 72

r.php on line 5↩ but when I went to submit yesterday everything was working except the css I don't see where is the error . thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no PHP error in the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you very much I will leave like that and give up with the css style 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet is that `site_url()` function fails. And as an error message contains `"`, your `HTML` code is getting messed up. Check the `HTML` after `PHP` interpretation.

Comment: thank you everyone I had a typo error in my function I missed the s from https//

Answer (score 0):

For CSS and JS files

- It could be because of your site_url() does not have last DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR (/)
- Your .htaccess file can forbid the files
- You created a route that forbid you access the path

I prefer application structure for PHP Core

```
your_best_application/
    app/
    modules/
    storage/
    public/
        css/
        js/
        fonts/
        images/
        .htaccess
        index.php
    logs/
    routes
```

With that application structure you will avoid from errors while get static files.

I hope it will help you.